# How were new states admitted to the Union?

Tags: united-states, constitution, articles-of-confederation

Admission of new states into the United States must be consistent with Article IV, Section 3 of the Constitution, but that leaves some discretion to Congress in a number of matters. **What were the different ways of proceeding and which states were admitted according to which processes?**

I know some examples of different ways of proceeding in the admission of states, but I also know my understanding is very incomplete, and I'm not sure any books deal with this question systematically.  Examples:

- With many states, the act of Congress said that the new state would be admitted when the president signed a certain document on a certain date, but with some other states, it simply said the new state would be admitted on a specified future date.  With the first two of the states admitted under Article IV, Vermont and Kentucky, the latter procedure was followed.
- Vermont and Texas make the transition directly from being a foreign country to being a state in the U.S.A. (Hawaii went through an intermediate period of some decades between foreign-country status and being a full-fledged state.)  Vermont's de-facto independence was vehemently but ineffectually disputed by New York, and New York's governor George Clinton successfully campaigned against Vermont's admission for a long time; otherwise it would have happened almost a decade earlier under the Articles of Confederation (in a sense it almost did happen in 1781 but Clinton exerted great efforts to stop it, and did).
- Congress granted Texas the right to split itself into several states without any further action by Congress.
- In Vermont the state constitution that had already been in effect for years simply continued in effect with no changes at all when the state was admitted, and the governor and other state officers who were already in office under that constitution simply continued their terms of office without even so much as getting sworn in in the manner prescribed by the federal Constitution.  (Might something similar have happened in Texas?)
- Kentucky was a part of Virginia until it became a separate state in 1792. Under Article IV, Section III, this required the consent of the legislature of Virginia, which was given in 1789. (I think governing such an extensive state was expensive and inconvenient and they also wanted more southerners in the U.S. senate.) Strangely, the act of Congress admitting Kentucky was actually passed two weeks *before* the act admitting Vermont, although Kentucky was not admitted until well over a year after Vermont. Because of New York's claim that Vermont was legally part of New York (although Vermont was under a government that refused to recognize that), Vermont could not be admitted until New York's legislature consented in 1790.  Maine could similarly not be admitted (in 1820) without the consent of the legislature of Massachusetts (granted in 1819, I think?) and West Virginia was a strange case, admitted during the Civil War with the consent of some anti-secessionist legislators in Virginia.

Comment: They could be forced in by executive order. Or annexation. Or by people just calling them a state.

Comment: I think at the core, this is a good list question. The core question is "How were states admitted to the Union?" - there are less than 50 answers (some are grouped, probably some discussions of "not admitted").  I would argue that the answer is both interesting and educational. Let's answer the question.

Comment: Rhode Island was admitted under threat; if Rhode Island did not join, it would be treated as a foreign power (comment rather than answer because I can't find my source - feel free to steal it).  Although it was one of the original 13, RI dragged feet as long as possible to deal with debt problems caused by land speculators. Eventually the other states demanded that RI join or be foreign - which was a bit more serious when government income was through tariffs.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace : It seems more to the point to say Rhode Island _joined_ rather than that Rhode Island "was admitted".  Article IV Section 3 did not apply to Rhode Island and no act of Congress was needed.

Comment: @DJSims They can not be forced in by executive order or annexation. You can't just call it a state.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent article on [Admission to the Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union) including sections on the [Admission Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union#Admission_process), some [notable exceptions from the norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union#States_that_were_never_part_of_an_organized_U.S._territory), and some [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_to_the_Union#Notes) on additional special cases. What this article does not cover however is a related topic of interest... (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)... and that is the process of re-admission to the Union for the states of the Confederacy.  While this [Lumen Learning material](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-ushistory2os2xmaster/chapter/restoring-the-union/) covers the re-admission process nicely as an overiew, a more detailed record can be found in Ohio History Central's more detailed [article on Reconstruction](http://www.ohiohistorycentral.org/w/Reconstruction). The question of re-admission to the Union is interesting because the North held that secession was illegal - thus if secession was not legal possible, (cont'd)..

Comment: (cont'd) ... why require re-admission to the Union?  That very question (among others) led to some fiery debate and conflict and the impeachment of a President!

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have been researching this off and on for a couple of weeks - compiling info for a possible answer.  It is turning into a longer answer than I originally expected and the research time is piling up.  Not sure if there is still any interest in this 2+ year old question or not.  Don't want to spend further effort if interest has waned or if answers have been obtained elsewhere.

Comment: @KerryL : "Readmission" after the civil war seems to be a tangent. I don't know the legalities, but it appears to be a different thing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - agreed, re-admission would be a tangent.  I've only spent a couple days on that tangent though in contrast to a couple weeks on the actual question. Either way, it's been an interesting journey - just don't know if the time it would take to finish researching and then compiling into an intelligible answer would be worth the effort. Possibly the general links I shared in my first comment would suffice for your purpose (?)

Answer (score 3):

Not only were they "re-admitted," but some were thrown out a second time for failure to act upon the 14th and 15th Amendments. Look at these dates: Secession, then readmission, and finally "returned to local rule."

> The Confederate States of America:
>
> South Carolina: -Seceded: Dec. 20, 1860 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb. 4,
> 1861 -Readmitted into U.S.: July 9, 1868 -Local rule reestablished:
> Nov. 28, 1876
>
> Mississippi: -Seceded: Jan. 9, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb. 4, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: Beg. 23, 1870 -Local rule reestablished: Jan. 4, 1876
>
> Florida: -Seceded: Jan 10, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb. 4, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: June 25, 1868       -Local rule reestablished: Jan 2, 1877
>
> Alabama: -Seceded: Jan. 11, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb. 4, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: July 14, 1868   -Local rule reestablished: Nov. 16, 1874
>
> Georgia: -Seceded: Jan. 19, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb 4, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: July 15, 1870      -Local rule reestablished: Nov. 1, 1871
>
> Louisiana: -Seceded Jan. 26, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Feb. 4, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: June 25, 1868 or July 9, 1868 -Local rule reestablished: Jan. 2, 1877
>
> Texas: -Seceded: Feb. 1, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: Mar. 2, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: Mar. 30, 1870       -Local rule reestablished: Jan. 14, 1873
>
> Virginia: -Seceded: April 17, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: May 7, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: Jan. 26, 1870   -Local rule reestablished: Oct. 5, 1869
>
> Arkansas: -Seceded: May 6, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: May 18, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: June 22, 1868 -Local rule reestablished: Nov. 10, 1874
>
> Tennessee: -Seceded: May 6, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: May 16, 1861
> -Readmitted into U.S.: July 24, 1866 -Local rule reestablished: Oct. 4, 1869
>
> North Carolina: -Seceded: May 21, 1861 -Admitted into C.S.: May 16,
> 1861 -Readmitted into U.S.: July 4, 1868 -Local rule reestablished
> Nov. 28, 1876
>
> *Sourced from https://web.archive.org/web/20130128092221/http://civilwartalk.com/threads/dates-of-southern-states-readmitted-to-the-u-s-and-local-rule-reestablished.19808 via https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-order-of-states-being-admitted-to-the-Confederacy/answer/Tuan-Nguyen-355?share=1*

Then there's Mississippi, with a filing error. The [movie Lincoln reminded them to ratify](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207223228/http://www.cbsnews.com/news/after-148-years-mississippi-finally-ratifies-13th-amendment-which-banned-slavery) the [13th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#cite_ref-Mississippi13thAmendmentABCNews_82-0), [officially filed Feb. 7, 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627203637/https://abcnews.go.com/blogs/headlines/2013/02/mississippi-officially-abolishes-slavery-ratifies-13th-amendment/).

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was curious too, https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53992 should help, I added the link. I'm glad Lincoln was made a movie, just for another additional reason now, apparently the film was educational enough to remind them to finally ratify (true story, and I added multiple source links just for that good reference in case others do not believe that at first either).